# Performing a "For Each" in VB.NET to find a cell containing a specific value within a range

Tags: vb.net, excel, for-loop, each

colhead basically is my string for column header. It pulls the column header name you want to look for from UniColCobo.text (which is a drop down menu on the windows form). Then it does a For Each from columns A to Z in the first row.

I am assuming I have the synax wrong as it's giving me "Invalid Cast Exception was Unhandled" on "If colhead = UniColCobo.Text Then"

```
Dim colhead As Object
        Dim TargetCol As Long

    colhead = Nothing

    MsgBox(oSheet.Cells(1, 1).value)

    For Each colhead In oSheet.Range("a1", "z1")

        If colhead = UniColCobo.Text Then

            TargetCol = colhead.Value

            MsgBox(TargetCol)

        End If



    Next colhead
```

Comment: You have colhead as an object and comparing it to a string. I'm pretty sure colhead isn't a string. Put a break point and a watch on it, look at what type of object it is. Also, how sure are you that colhead.Value is always a long?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
If colhead.Value = UniColCobo.Text Then
```

but if `colhead.Value` is a string then

```
TargetCol = colhead.Value
```

will fail, so I'm not sure what you're trying to get.

Comment: Good catch, targetcol should actually be colhead.column I will chnage that now.

I will try your adjustment for colhead.value